# install4j obsolete files not removed on upgrade

Tags: install4j

I am writing a sample upgrade installer and added in few files and removed up some files. I see that the added files are getting properly placed but the removed are not getting deleted.

how to handle this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an "Uninstall previous installation" action to the "Installation" screen of your installer in order to remove those files.

Comment: "UninstallPrevious installation" Would that make the entire product to be uninstalled?  I don't want to remove files that are modified by the customer on upgrades.But want to remove them on uninstallations. So the file installation options dictated for uninstall will they be acted if i call the "uninstall previous installation" action in installation screen?

Comment: Then you have to give those files an uninstall policy of "if created but not for update"